# MSXML on Windows mobile 6.1

Tags: windows-mobile, msxml, windows-mobile-6.1

I am a newbie and could not find any suitable answer on this forum.

How can I get MSXML on windows mobile 6.1 device? My project is .Net CF 3.5 based, language C# and would like to XSLT transformation capabilities. I got to know that it is possible to use MSXML in windows pc os. But how to make it work for a windows mobile application?

Comment: Back before Microsoft killed the platform I was able to use MSXML.  I'm pretty sure it is in there, though I was doing native development and not .Net/CF.  Maybe CF lacks the necessary wrapper classes for this COM library?

Answer (score 0):

I have used the gnome xml libraries successfully on WindowsCE. Both libxml2 and libxslt are a good avenue to explore for you requirements.

I have also successfully used libxmlsec, which I doubt Microsoft is even close to supporting.